# AUCTeX: custom ‘fill-nobreak-predicate’ hook to respect braces

Tags: emacs, autofill, auctex

I use the following C-ish indentation/bracing style when writing LaTeX code:

```
\foo{
  blah blah... this line is getting too long and should be wrapped
}
```

whenever I need to re-wrap (technically, *refill*) a block/paragraph, according to `fill-column` option (50 in this example),  I hit `M-q`. That also changes the braces' position:

```
\foo{ blah blah blah... this line is getting too
  long and should be wrapped }
```

which hurts my eyes :-( 
Indeed I'd like to *keep* the braces in their *original position*, namely:

```
\foo{ 
  blah blah blah... this line is getting too
  long and should be wrapped 
}
```

I guess I should add a custom `fill-nobreak-predicate` hook for AUCTeX, or customize `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate`, but I'm not that skilled with emacs lisp...

Since this question might apply to any markup-text-mode, fill free to move it upstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Stefan suggestion., I come up with this, Seems working well, for simple tests,

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
            (setq paragraph-separate (concat " *}\\|^ *\\\\[a-zA-Z]* ?{\\|"
                                              paragraph-separate))))
```

Comment: Thanks, it does a good job. It fails on stuff like `\foo {` (there's a space), though I can force correct behaviour by appending a comment sign, à la `\foo {%`...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, no fill-nobreak-predicate is (as the name implies) to avoid breaking the line at some places, whereas you want to *force* break the line at some places.  You'll probably be better served by `paragraph-separate`: declare the a line that only contains `}` or only `\cmd{` should not be considered as part of a paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, could you please add a configuration example?